# Modelling a particle under the influence of an electric field with a restoring force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, computational-physics, spring, differential-equations

Suppose I have a particle under the influence of an electric field. The particle is also attached to a spring. The particle should therefore feel the influence of two forces such that the total force is then:

\begin{align}
F_T &= F_E + F_S\\
&= qE - kx
\end{align}
where $k$ is just the spring constant. This is then a second order differential equation:

$$
m\frac{\mathrm d^2x}{\mathrm dt^2} = qE - kx
$$

What I am struggling with is solving this equation such that I get an expression for $\Delta x$ which is essentially the distance moved by the particle in some interval $\Delta t$.

For context, the spring is a rough model for the surface tension of a surrounding material pulling the particle back toward the equilibrium point of the surface. This is going into a computer model, with arbitrary time-steps, with each step calculating the change in $x$, $\Delta x$. To be clear, the potential applied to the particle is constant, but the electric field depends upon $x$. So if we say that the particle is being attracted toward some source, the field strength and therefore the force will increase as the particle moves closer to the source.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, then please add the homework-and-exercises tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general trick is to convert the one second-order differential into two first-order ones. This is done by introducing an extra variable to carry around:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}&=f(x,\,t)\\
\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}&=v
\end{align}
for whatever function $f(\cdot)$ you need.

This can easily be applied to numerical integration schemes (Runge-Kutta, verlet, etc) for which you seem to be interested in.

Given the electric field under consideration here, you will likely end up with a current being generated, and hence have the magnetic field play a role (though perhaps you could argue for not including it). In either event, you be interested in [particle in cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle-in-cell) method (has been discussed on this site as well).